# How can we add customized module in openerp 7?

Tags: python, odoo

Is it possible to add new customized module in openerp? How can we add new module and how to handle database for new module?

what are prerequisites for openerp customization?

Are there any demerits by openerp customization? if there can you please list them for me?

What should I want to learn for customization?

Comment: First of all you should read the docs: https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev_01/

Comment: Thank you for giving me good suggestion. Sure I'll

Comment: Such a nice tutorial thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through http://blog.openerp4you.in/2013/06/how-to-create-module-in-openerp.html link. They have given easy explaination :)

Comment: But I'm using version7. It doesn't make a difference ?

Comment: Nope, this mechanism is same for both v7 and trunk :)